# modular addition for unsigned number in c

Tags: c, binary, overflow, addition

i don't understand something when combining signed and unsigned numbers in c.
Why the expression `0u - 1`, give me the max value(depending on word size) of the unsigned integer.??

Comment: When you do arithmetic with both signed and unsigned numbers, the signed number is converted to an unsigned number. This winds up being (0 - 1) unsigned which is the largest possible unsigned number.

Comment: @malisper `signed` and `unsigned` versions of the same type follow that rule. If `long` or `short` is thrown into the mix things get confusing again.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard

> — The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the
>   corresponding signed integer type, if any.

And according to the usual arithmetic conversion

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
>   the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with unsigned integer type.

`Unsigned int` type preserves the value of an object of `signed int` type.

In this expression

```
0u - 1;
```

1 is converted to unsigned type and the expression is equivalent to

```
0u - 1u
```

There is used unsigned arithmetic. The result consists of all bits set to 1 that is equivalent to the maximum unsigned value.

The operation look like ( for simplicity I will use only four bits)

```
0000
-
0001
====

10000  <= borrowing one high-order bit to provide the operation
-
0001
====
01111
=====
1111
```

Comment: let work with 8bits, i tought that -1 is first converted to unsigned 0xFF(1111 1111) and then we do the addition 0 + 0xFF ?? that not how it work?

Comment: @karim In your expression there is the binary minus operator. It is not the same as the unary minus. So there is no such an operand as -1.